# How to make company own login button

Tags: authentication

I am working for a company. I am required to make a login button for their own server, such as google and facebook for their different applications. My question is how i will be able to create these buttons, for our different apps, e.g. android, Java servers etc. Furthermore the server has nothing in place for this (i.e. generating the app id etc.), I would be able to figure that out. Is there anyone with any guidance towards this, maybe a few links.

Just to be clear, i am not looking for a implementation for the google/facebook login buttons, I want people to be able to add a "Our Company Login" button to their apps.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are off-topic. You could try typing something like "how does facebook login work" into Google which would probably get you the name of the relevant standard.